# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment shows Network error 400

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

YouTubePlayerSupportFragment shows Network error 400

I have created small demo to test YoutubeSupportFragment

```
 YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youtube_player_fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
        youtube_player_fragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if (null == youTubePlayer) return;
                if (!b) {
                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                    youTubePlayer.cuePlaylist("zuf8A0udHrs");


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
        FrameLayout youtube_player_frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_frame);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtube_player_frame, youtube_player_fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you even have an internet connection ?
Maybe try on another phone because there you are in Roaming mode maybe it doesnt work in there ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried in 2 mobile phones with latest version of youtube application is installed

Comment: Try to do it with just a vido not a playlist... youTubePlayer.cueVideo("1jcvCZEyZkE");

Comment: its video only i have used

Comment: try to youTubePlayer.cueVideo("1jcvCZEyZkE")  instead of youTubePlayer.cuePlaylist("zuf8A0udHrs");

Comment: thank you It solved my problem but still it now shows other error YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout{a13189d V.E...... ........ 0,112-720,1022}. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 30, top: 504, right: 30, bottom: 26..